# Is it correct to say that using MySQL running on SSD disk on a server makes it comparable in performance to NoSQL Db?

Tags: mysql, nosql

As it is well known performance impact is quite significant when using the new SSD as opposed the old disk drives. If MySQL database including all the data is on SSD, how does that compare to NoSQL database on SSD such as MongoDB in terms of run time performance?

This will be used in application requiring hundreds if not thousands of queries and updates per second.

Comment: It depends. NoSQL isn't about performance. It's about being non-relational.

Comment: Bunch of questions here: 1) Are you comparing MySQL+SSD to NoSQL+HD, or to NoSQL+SSD?  2) What kind of queries / requests are you making of the database? 3) Why do you want to know (because that information will help drive the correct answer)?   The answer may be: Try it and find out.

Comment: Ist it correct.....? - No. Apples and Oranges. In some cases it will be faster, in other slower.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong on this as I'm far from a NoSQL expert but I believe the overhead of a traditional RDBMS is not entirely limited to disk i/o.  NoSQL databases like MongoDB lack features like transactions which make MySQL more stable.  Something like memcached might be a better way to go to speed up mysql performance while maintaining the reliability of an RDBMS